# Getting calendar appointments working on WP7 but not WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, appointment

When I run codes of [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.userdata.appointments.searchcompleted%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in windows phone 7 project it's ok but when I test it in a windows phone 8 project it gets exception at this line:

```
appts.SearchAsync(start, end, 20, "Appointments Test #1");
```

I can't understand what's the reason???

Comment: Do you enable related capability?

Comment: @Ku6opr could you please explain more?

Comment: what kind of exception? what was the error message?

Comment: add `<Capability Name="ID_CAP_APPOINTMENTS" />` to `<Capabilities>` section in `WMAppManifest.xml` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add related capablity to use appointments: copy and paste `<Capability Name="ID_CAP_APPOINTMENTS" />` to `<Capabilities>` section in `WMAppManifest.xml` file